# How do I reliably draw a 1px border around the viewport?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work out how to draw a 1px border around the viewport. I would have thought this would do it, but it doesn't. It mostly draws the border, but when resizing the browser the right and bottom border constantly disappear.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Something</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: blue;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Cropped border]

Comment: Works for me  - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jOMXQGz

Comment: Do you have content other than what you said here? If so, please show more code.

Comment: No, that's the entire page.

Comment: Using Chrome 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit) resizing the browser constantly crops the right and bottom border.

Comment: I have the same chrome browser version ( Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build), (64 bit) ), but it works well for me. Then show a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Ditto - No issue here.

Comment: Have you tried resizing it a few times?

Comment: Also tested in Firefox, which seems to always draw the right border, but never the bottom.

Comment: 1px of red over blue isn't the best for eyes. Made it thicker and you can better see it

Comment: I wonder whether this is an artifact of hidpi pixel mapping, it's a pretty high resolution screen 3140x2160 and the effect appears to disappear completely if I make the border 2px. I have a 1080p monitor somewhere, I'll dig that out and see how it behaves on that.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like below:

```css
html::after {
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:1px solid red;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your problem, but a thought could be to use an `outline` instead. It uses almost the same syntax as `border`, but you can add a negative `outline-offset` to make it like an "inset shadow".

```css
         html, body {
            height: 100%;
         }
         body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: blue;
            outline: 1px solid red;
            outline-offset: -1px;
         }
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a pseudo-elemnt like in this case that spans 100vh and 100vw and has a position fixed. However the entire rest must be wrapped aswell and use an overflow rules as otherwise the body scrollbar will cut away the right side border.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.viewport-border {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 7px);
  width: calc(100vw - 7px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport-border"></div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to put the border around the **viewport** (as the question suggests), and ***not*** around the **document** (as other answers seem to have assumed).

You'll want to use a `position: fixed;` element with a high `z-index` value:

```html
<div id="viewportBorder"></div>
```

```css
div#viewportBorder {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

Here it is in action:

```css
body {
  background: #09f;
}

div#viewportBorder {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* not technically needed in this example, but you might need it in your project */
  z-index: 999999;
}

.spacer-to-allow-scrolling {
  height: 300vh;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, white);
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="viewportBorder"></div>
  <div class="spacer-to-allow-scrolling"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Update:** thank you to Temani Afif for pointing this out:

> worth to note that your element will hide everything and you cannot have any interaction with the content (clicking, selecting, etc) you may need to consider pointer-events:none

Comment: worth to note that your element will hide everything and you cannot have any interaction with the content (clicking, selecting, etc) you may need to consider pointer-events:none

Comment: @TemaniAfif Very true. Thank you. Can't believe I forgot that :) I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work for me. Works fine in a web IDE of course like all these other solutions, probably because in the web base IDE the 1px border isn't actually the border of the browser itself.

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome on a 2K display without any issues.

Comment: please remove the space after id="viewportBorder in your first code block. It will solve copy and paste issues